# How can a producer detect if a consumer is attached?

Tags: v4l2loopback

I'm using v4l2loopback plus a program I wrote to produce a virtual camera stream.  Right now, I start and stop my program by hand when it's needed.  I'd rather have it run as a daemon always, and only produce output when there's a consumer attached to the device.

Is there a way for a v4l2loopback producer to detect if a consumer is attached?  It looks like `poll` always returns ready for writing, I don't see an ioctl for this, or changes in the buffer flags or other behavior.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I kept looking, and found an issues thread discussing this: https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/109

It looks like there isn't something built into v4l2loopback, but [one comment](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/109#issuecomment-617638198) does suggest using inotify.  inotify isn't the most robust solution, but it's something.

Answer (score 0):

Latest v4l2loopback supports VIDIOC_SUBSCRIBE_EVENT
When a client connects, you will receive a V4L2_EVENT_PRI_CLIENT_USAGE event.